# How can I defeat Metal Runners?

Tags: terra-battle

Metal (and Gold) Runners show up quite frequently in the Metal Zone, but their tendency to move away as soon as a unit gets close to them makes them feel like a certain [Kung Fu-knowing protagonist](http://basementrejects.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/the-matrix-billboard.jpg). How can I beat these little nuisances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metal runners are vulnerable to sleep.  So if you can start a chain on the orbs with a sleep user they'll often put the runners to sleep so you have a few turns to set up a chain to kill them.

At later levels their vulnerability changes to other status affects like paralysis, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that they move away when your unit actually touches them. When I move very carefully (and slowly) they tend to not move away. Essentially, don't bump them at all and they stay still.

Answer (score 1):

> **Metal Runners and Gold Runners**
>
> Metal Runners and Gold Runners are worth more experience than the
>   regular enemies, but will move if you move characters close to them.
>   They are sensitive to speed and vulnerable to
>   sleep/paralysis/confusion/petrification (different for each zone).
>   Gold Runners are more sensitive to speed than Metal Runners. There are
>   two ways of dealing with runners.
>
> 1. Bring character(s) with a sleep/paralysis/confusion/petrification skill. The Mech Orbling is a rank C monster that you can recruit from
>      Tavern early on and has a area 2 sleeping gas skill. See our skill
>      page for characters with these skills.
> 2. Move slowly around runners. Since runners are sensitive to speed, there's a chance they will not move.
>
> Attempting to surround runners is possible but difficult.

from http://www.terrabattlex.com/zones/metal